# How do I change the plymouth bootscreen?

Tags: plymouth

With regards to Plymouth --

Are there alternative boot screens available?

What's the easiest way to change the boot screen?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can get a list of themes available via the repositories through [Synaptic Package Manager](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) or through the command line via `aptitude`:

```
$ aptitude search plymouth-theme
p   lubuntu-plymouth-theme        - plymouth theme for Lubuntu
p   plymouth-theme-fade-in        - graphical boot animation and logger - fade-in theme
p   plymouth-theme-glow           - graphical boot animation and logger - glow theme
i   plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo   - graphical boot animation and logger - kubuntu-logo theme
p   plymouth-theme-sabily         - plymouth theme for Sabily
p   plymouth-theme-script         - graphical boot animation and logger - script theme
p   plymouth-theme-solar          - graphical boot animation and logger - solar theme
p   plymouth-theme-spinfinity     - graphical boot animation and logger - spinfinity theme
p   plymouth-theme-text           - graphical boot animation and logger - text theme
c   plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo    - graphical boot animation and logger - ubuntu-logo theme
i   plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text    - graphical boot animation and logger - ubuntu-logo theme
p   plymouth-theme-ubuntustudio   - Ubuntu Studio Plymouth theme
p   xubuntu-plymouth-theme        - Plymouth theme for Xubuntu
```

You can then install the resulting packages via Synaptic or apt as normal:

```
$ sudo apt install plymouth-theme-solar
```

If you're looking for something not in the repositories, [UbuntuGeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/) has an excellent tutorial on how to [install and create your own custom Plymouth themes](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/quick-tipplymouth-themes-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx.html).

Comment: Be careful because not all of the themes support the boot messages generated by Ubuntu.

Comment: `apt` works as wel.

Comment: Tried `sudo apt install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo` on 20.10 -- still "kubuntu" logo on boot.

Answer (score 91):

To change between the installed themes you should do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

The first will list available themes to choose from, the second command with update initramfs with a new theme.

Comment: Cool -- still works in 11.10.

Comment: Still works in 16.10, as well

Comment: ...and 17.10, too

Comment: ... still works in 18.04

Comment: ... still works in 18.10

Comment: ... still works in 20.04

Comment: ...still works in 21.10

Answer (score 81):

## Getting Started Guide

**Editing Plymouth**

You can edit [Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth) with a simple text editor for animations and images.  This is Ubuntu version agnostic.

[image: Original to New]

- Get Template
- Customize Template
- Set Custom Theme

### Make a template

First you will get a template that covers all the basic aspects of a Plymouth.  Change `my-theme` to your own personal them name.

```
sudo cp --recursive /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo ~/themes/my-theme
```

### Customize file names

Now you can change some names to help identify our theme from others.

```
sudo mv ubuntu-logo.plymouth my-theme.plymouth
sudo mv ubuntu-logo.script my-theme.script
sudo mv ubuntu-logo.grub my-theme.grub
sudo mv ubuntu_logo16.png my_theme16.png
sudo mv ubuntu_logo.png my_theme.png
```

### Edit image files

Use your image editor of choice to alter the **png** images.  I like [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) for quick edits.

```
gimp my_theme.png my_theme16.png 
gimp progress_dot_on.png progress_dot_off.png 
gimp progress_dot_on16.png progress_dot_off16.png
```

Here is an example of my alterations:

> [image: screenshot]
>   [image: screenshot]
>   [image: screenshot]
>   [image: screenshot]
>   [image: screenshot]
>   [image: screenshot]

### Edit the configuration files.

1. Set up theme information file.

   ```
   gedit my-theme.plymouth
   ```

   Edit lines **2**, **7**, and **8** and change ubuntu logo to you theme name.

   ```
   [Plymouth Theme]
   Name=My Theme
   Description=A theme that features a blank background with a logo.
   ModuleName=script

   [script]
   ImageDir=/lib/plymouth/themes/my-theme
   ScriptFile=/lib/plymouth/themes/my-theme/my-theme.script
   ```
2. Start-up terminal color. (Optional)

   ```
   gedit my-theme.grub
   ```

   Change it from purple to something else.

   Edit line **1** with RGB color code.

   A good site to help you is [Color-Hex](http://www.color-hex.com). I am just going to make mine black.

   ```
   if background_color 0,0,0; then
     clear
   fi
   ```
3. The script file to apply theme changes

   ```
   gedit my-theme.script
   ```

   There is many different aspects to this file that you can change to customize your plymouth boot theme. If you wish to do more advanced changes you should study it.  I am only showing how to change the background color, logo, and status indicator.

   Edit lines **169**, **170**, **174**, and **180** to change the background gradient and images you edited earlier.

   ```
   Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.66, 0.66, 0.66);       #top 
   Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0.146, 0.146, 0.146); #bottom

   bits_per_pixel = Window.GetBitsPerPixel ();
   if (bits_per_pixel == 4) {
       logo_filename = "my_theme16.png";
       progress_dot_off_filename = "progress_dot_off16.png";
       progress_dot_on_filename = "progress_dot_on16.png";
       password_field_filename = "password_field16.png";
       question_field_filename = "password_field16.png";
   } else {
       logo_filename = "my_theme.png";
       progress_dot_off_filename = "progress_dot_off.png";
       progress_dot_on_filename = "progress_dot_on.png";
       password_field_filename = "password_field.png";
       question_field_filename = "password_field.png";
   }
   ```

### Send your theme folder

```
cp --recursive ~/themes/my-theme /lib/plymouth/themes
```

### Set Plymouth configuration to use theme.

```
sudo ln -sf /lib/plymouth/themes/my-theme/my-theme.plymouth /etc/alternatives/default.plymouth
sudo ln -sf /lib/plymouth/themes/my-theme/my-theme.grub /etc/alternatives/default.plymouth.grub
```

---

### 18.04+

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

### Restart to watch it in action.

Comment: I would upvote this more than once if I could. Thank you for the very thorough and detailed explanation/guide.

Comment: @mason81 Thank you very much.  I don't know about thorough, but it leads you to all avenues if you have the self learning ability(ie. animations, positions, etc).

Comment: For 17.10+, replace `/lib/plymouth/themes` with `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`

Comment: @PJSingh thank you for the update.  I was looking at installing that version shortly, I'll verify and add update.

Comment: Still works in 18.04, but running `sudo update-initramfs -u` helps to ensure that it works first time.  One thing I'm not clear on though: before the plymouth theme becomes active, my install seems to have the default purple background for a few seconds, have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

To install a new theme:
`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/mytheme/mytheme.plymouth 80`

To actually active a new theme:
`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`

Finally do a
`sudo update-initramfs -u`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and I came here. No luck. I started randomly browsing around the Plymouth framework, and I noticed the `default.plymouth` file was a linked file. Every time I set the splash screen with the terminal, the file updates. Through trial and error, I found this method.

In the terminal, type in the following:
`gksu [file_explorer_name]`

This will open a new window, with root (superuser) permissions to edit, delete, and add files. Navigate to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/`. This is where your themes are located. If your theme folder isn't in the plymouth themes folder, move it. In your themes folder, find a `.plymouth` file, and open it in your default text editor. Look at the directories, and make sure they're accurate and up-to-date. Save and exit the text editor. Make a LINKED file of your `.plymouth` file, and drag it to the themes folder (/usr/share/plymouth/themes/) and rename it as `default.plymouth` You need to delete the existing files (if any) in the themes folder. After that, you should be able to close the window and terminal, then reboot to test the configuration.