# What is the 'bizcom' logo that's appeared following my upgrade?

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, plymouth

I upgraded to 11.10, and now I notice that when I shut down, I get a weird "bizcom" logo with a backwards copyright symbol:

[image: bzicom]

At first this made me think I had installed some dubious hacked package, but I haven't found any.  Then I thought it might be related to my newish Asus monitor, and something the upgrade triggered so that it goes into its own shutdown mode.  This doesn't seem to be the case either (even though Ubuntu now identifies the monitor by OEM name that's new to me, "Ancor Communications".).
Where is this "bizcom" image coming from, and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this is related to a Plymouth theme, and I was able to revert it, though I'd like to know the history of this "bizcom" thing.

In the past, I changed plymouth themes, and I'm guessing there must have been a configuration fallback with the upgrade that gave me the "bizcom" image.

The image is part of the "glow" theme.  (I discovered this through a combination of Google searches and manually going through plymouth image directories with 'Eye of Gnome'). 
The "throbber" images, e.g., `/lib/plymouth/themes/glow/throbber-19.png` match the image I was seeing.

I followed the suggestion from this question, 
[How do I change the plymouth bootscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen) , and ran 
`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`

I changed the theme to `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth` and the strange bizcom logo disappeared, and I have the expected Ubuntu branding back.

Comment: Did you find out why it says Bizcom? I got the same strange appearance in my Plymouth today.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the definitive answer to this question is to ask
Ray Strode of Red Hat

```
https://www.zoominfo.com/p/Ray-Strode/1090769932
```

why he added this logo to the Freedesktop Plymouth repository in commit     7f743227c3634207e1fb0ec7f9e7d69bb0259d71 on 2008-05-30 at 13:10:19h EDT.

As a result of this addition, the image was then included as the default banner logo on Plymouth themes distributed downstream by Fedora, Opensuse, Ubuntu etc

Perhaps at the time, it was the logo of Bizcom web services and was intended to be free advertising for them.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu and thank you for contributing. Please take the [tour]. I don't know if it was a deliberate choice to format the zoominfo link as a code block, but hyperlinking text is answers is easily done.  If you change your mind, you can [edit] your question at any time.