# How to Ubuntu change the Plymouth theme?

Tags: boot, 13.04, plymouth

Is there any safe tool for changing Plymouth theme.

I found a couple of tools but as I found users commenting that those tools mess up one's system I didn't try them.

Can you recommend some good tools?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the plymouth bootscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Plymouth Manager? It's easy to use.

Check the Plymouth Manager site/blog here: http://plymouthmanager.wordpress.com/

Comment: Please add how to change the theme with that tool to really answer the question.

Comment: This tool has not been updated since 2011.