# Script for Plymouth theme for 18.04

Tags: 18.04, themes, plymouth

I currently have 2 image files which I wish to work in a loop for boot screen / Plymouth theme. I referred to some existing themes and finally settled with the following file structure `\lib\plymouth\themes\black`

[image]

I think everything is set if I can have a `black.script` file with code that tells the system to play the images files in loop and include possibly some standard fail safe code.

It would be great if someone here can help me create the required code. Thanks.

Comment: Here's something to get started: https://askubuntu.com/questions/828380/newly-added-plymouth-theme-not-showing-up-during-boot/848437#848437

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix . I was hoping that black.script file should be the only one to fix it.

Comment: Don't worry. Spending your free time over next couple weeks and you'll be all done.