# Bootloader that leaves UEFI logo on screen

Tags: bootloader, grub-efi

Is there a bootloader or a setting for Grub that does not clear the (entire) screen, leaving the UEFI logo (motherboard logo)  in place - just like Windows 10 shows the progress circles below whatever the logo was shown at boot?

Comment: You can customize Ubuntu's boot logo that is displayed by `plymouth` to look exactly like the manufacturer logo. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen

Comment: Actually, it seems the Windows bootloader is able to read and use the logo directly from UEFI. I'm using refind now and when I boot into Windows (after the refind screen, which is all black) the UEFI logo comes back on screen.