# Remove kubuntu-desktop package and revert associated changes from Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, desktop-environments

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 17.10. I wanted to try out the plasma desktop so I did

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`

`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

and selected lightdm. I tried it out for about a day and then wanted to remove it. I have done

`sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop`

`sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-*`

`sudo apt-get purge plasma-desktop`

`sudo apt-get purge plasma-*`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

all multiple times and in different orders and every time now it lists a bunch of packages and says "not installed, so not removed."

My problem is that (1) the lock screen is no longer the new gnome one that came with the 17.01 upgrade, (2) it still says kubuntu on reboot and startup, and (3) my trackpad scrolling is now inverted with no way of changing this. I will be more than happy to backup my files and do a fresh install of ubuntu after my finals but I just want to know if there is anything else I should try / should have done.

Comment: your issue 1 can be fixed with `dpkg-reconfigure gdm` (16.04 used lightdm; 17.10 uses gnome's dm; I guess you're using whatever kubuntu used). issues 2 is just the plymouth [graphic] which shows on startup/shutdown; pick another like your original ubuntu... (refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth or https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen). sorry I can't help with issue 3 sorry.

Answer (score 0):

use tasksel to remove kubuntu-desktop and KDE then use tasksel to install your favourite desktop. Install tasksel using sudo apt install tasksel if not already installed.

Comment: I did this. Kubuntu desktop was not checked off. I tried installing Vanilla GNOME and got "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."