# Plymouth Don't Show On Starting Just Show on shutDown

Tags: plymouth

i recently installed Plymouth and use a custom theme ,i did all the things but my screen splash just show on shutdown screen and i get blank screen on booting , i use every way but i didn't get any answer, can anyone answer and help me?

Answer (score 0):

'i did all the things' and 'i use every way' is not explaining what you did. Maybe you can reinstall Plymouth, ($ sudo apt-get install --reinstall Plymouth) or check another theme. Which program did you use to install the theme or did you so by hand? maybe you can find your answer here: [How do I change the plymouth bootscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen).