# How can I remove Budgie from my OS?

Tags: package-management, budgie

My OS is Ubuntu vanilla 18.04, I installed `Plank Preferences` from Ubuntu Software, then when I turn on/off my computer Ubuntu Budgie screen shows up, sometimes when I power off my computer, it stays at Budgie screen for a while, I think it was updating something.
How can I remove all the settings of Budgie? Removing `Plank Preferences` doesn't change anything.

Here are the Budgie related packages, but I don't know which one I can remove, I don't want to screw up my OS.

```
rc  budgie-core                          10.4+git20171031.10.g9f amd64    Core package for Budgie-Desktop
rc  budgie-desktop-common                0.9.9                   all      Common Ubuntu Budgie desktop components customisation
rc  budgie-desktop-environment           0.9.9                   all      Desktop environment customisation for Ubuntu Budgie
ii  gir1.2-budgie-1.0                    10.4+git20171031.10.g9f amd64    GNOME introspection library for budgie-desktop
ii  libbudgie-plugin0                    10.4+git20171031.10.g9f amd64    Plugin library for budgie-desktop
ii  libraven0                            10.4+git20171031.10.g9f amd64    Raven library for budgie-desktop
ii  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-budgie-logo    0.9.6                   all      graphenter code hereical boot animation and logger - Ubuntu Budgie logo theme
ii  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-budgie-text    0.9.6                   all      graphical boot animation and logger - Ubuntu Budgie text theme
```

Comment: If you mean you see the screen before you get the login (greeter) screen, then its the plymouth screen you are seeing on power on & off.     See https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen for changing it.  The plymouth screen is just a graphic used to hide the power-on text messages as your system boots & shutdowns down.

Comment: @guiverc Is it safe to remove those two plymouth packages and others?

Comment: I can't see why not; I looked at my own 18.04 system and none are installed (& mine has gnome, mate, xfce.. already). I would however read what is going to be removed when you do it, as it could be they were pulled in by a wanted/needed program (*b/c of dependencies, but here I'm thinking more of libs - plymouth packages will have zero effect on anything I believe*)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, how about the others, `budgie-core`, `budgie-desktop-common` and so on.

Comment: "rc" means the package was marked for removal; however config files remain on system.  ie. you installed it at some time, then removed it  however some config files remain;  I wouldn't worry about them.  The `gir1.2-budgie` is a library too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command.
Removes repo and plank.

sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ricotz/docky
sudo apt-get purge plank