# Why is my Ubuntu splash screen variable?

Tags: plymouth

Not a problem, but I am surprised that, since 18.10, my Ubuntu splash screen is not always the same.

By splash screen I mean what comes between Grub screen & Login screen.

Normally this is a quite large "ubuntu" sign plus Ubuntu circle of friends logo, with 5 sequencing dots underneath.
But sometimes, instead, I get a very small "Ubuntu 18.10" sign, without logo & with 4 sequencing dots overhead...

Any clarification gratefully received!

EDIT after guiverc reply:

Thanks, guiverc, for your helpful comments & links.

Whatever I have is by default - I never selected any plymouth screen.

Synapt shows me I have (installed), as you guessed:
- plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo (This package contains the default ubuntu-logo theme.)
- plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (This package contains the default ubuntu-text text theme used when no
support for a graphical theme is found on your system.)

So it sounds as though sometimes "no support for a graphical theme is found"...

Should I worry?

Comment: I don't know why you're seeing different screens, but the 'splash' screen you as seeing is a `plymouth` screen, a graphical image that is shown instead of the text boot messages that seem to scare average users. You can change this quite easily, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen  (*I suspect you're seeing the plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo  & tplymouth-theme-ubuntu-text as the alternate, but unsure as to why*)

Comment: I experience the different boot screen, when i had an unclean boot. It swtiches to kind of failsafe mode, which is textoutput only. This mostly happens after a new install of my nvidia driver.