# Uninstall Mate desktop environment from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, uninstall, mate

I installed Mate desktop environment in Ubuntu 18.04 as described in the [this blog.](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-mate-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

The following commands -

```
$ sudo apt install tasksel
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo tasksel install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

But I didn't like Mate therefore I tried to uninstall it -

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

But above command did not uninstall Mate environment completely.

How to remove Mate completely from Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: The `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` command just re-runs the post-installation script for package `gdm3` (gnome's display manager).  You should `sudo apt remove ubuntu-mate-desktop`

Answer (score 4):

To remove MATE DE completely you can use the following commands:

1. Parse `dpkg --list` output to get all mentions of MATE and then remove packages with MATE in its description:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg --list | grep MATE | awk '{print $2}')
   ```
2. Remove some leftover packages (including Plymouth boot screen) manually with commands below:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge libmate-sensors-applet-plugin0
   sudo apt-get purge libmateweather-common libmateweather1:amd64
   sudo apt-get purge mate-accessibility-profiles
   sudo apt-get purge mate-notification-daemon
   sudo apt-get purge mate-notification-daemon-common
   sudo apt-get purge plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-logo 
   sudo apt-get purge plymouth-theme-ubuntu-mate-text
   ```

   (they are presented by single lines to to be more fail-proof - to avoid the situation if one of them are not installed)
3. Install system components back if there were removed with previous commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk update-manager update-notifier
   ```
4. And then finally reconfigure your login screen with

   ```
   sudo dpkg-configure lightdm # for LightDM
   sudo dpkg-configure gdm3 # for GDM3
   ```

---

Note: the MATE itself is [more flexible](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/i-really-dont-like-brisk-menu/17708/2?u=norbert_x) than GNOME. Also you may want to try Xfce or KDE.

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` command just re-runs the post-installation script for package `gdm3` (gnome's display manager).  If you have more than one display manager installed, you'll be asked which you want to run, but no package changes will be made (that would require a `dpkg` or `apt` like command; the reverse of your `tasksel` which is a front-end tool for install meta packages - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel).

You should `sudo apt remove ubuntu-mate-desktop`, 
OR to remove remove configuration files as well `sudo apt purge ubuntu-mate-desktop`

You'll likely be left with the plymouth screen (which is the graphic that hides the boot messages) as that's not considered part of the desktop (it's like a wallpaper), so if that annoys you please refer to [How do I change the plymouth bootscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen) which will allow you to change the Ubuntu-MATE plymouth screen to any other you have installed.