# Ubuntu 19.10 with Kubuntu issue

Tags: kubuntu, 19.10, drag-and-drop

Ah couple of weeks ago I installed kubuntu-desktop along side gnome-desktop, but then I remove Kubuntu completely again, but since then the kubuntu logo shows up when I turn off and on the computer, also a lot of things don't work properly, for example I can't drag and drop files to the web browser now(Is not a web browser issue since I tries in different ones).

Does anybody know the solution to this?
Or should I reinstall Ubuntu in order to solve this?

Thanks for reading

Comment: "Please [edit] the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once." from [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions) in the section titled *Needs more focus*.

Comment: The `plymouth` screen is like a wallpaper image, yes it's installed as part of `kubuntu-desktop` but no it isn't removed when you removed the package. You only need to change default to whichever you choose (you can use a lubuntu one, ubuntu-mate, ubuntu-studio or a debian one, without installing any of those desktops or using debian (some debian ones are found in ubuntu too! *though I don't know if in 19.10 or just older release*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the plymouth bootscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen)