# Xubuntu on boot screen - how do I get the Ubuntu logo back?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, logo

I installed xubuntu just to have a lighter flavour of Ubuntu running on my rickety laptop. So I now have both Gnome and Xubuntu. Now when the laptop boots, it shows the Xubuntu logo and it's kinda annoying because I really love the purple Ubuntu logo. Any suggestions on how to get back the purple screen with the Ubuntu logo on it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the plymouth bootscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen) See Dima's answer.

Comment: Dima's answer is not complete. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `terminal`...

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-alternatives --config text.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```