# Kubuntu logo shows instead of the Ubuntu logo

Tags: boot, gnome, kubuntu

So I once tried out KDE Plasma by installing kubuntu-desktop. I then uninstalled it, but forgot to do auto-remove. I had to remove all software manually (it's all gone now) but I got another problem: Wrong logo shows when booting up my PC, instead of showing my manufacturer logo (in this case, ASUS), the Ubuntu logo, and the loading circle. When the Kubuntu logo is not showing, it shows a black screen. What can I do about this?

Note: I am a pretty new Linux user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the packages `plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo` and `plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text`.

This should revert to the default logo. If it still does not work, then try changing the plymouth theme (which is what determines this logo) using the answer by Dima [in this Askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen).

Comment: I only see the manufacturer logo. Nothing else.

Comment: I checked again after reboot, turns out I also forgot to mention I installed xubuntu-desktop, I did the same thing with Xubuntu as I did with Kubuntu. I'll give you an update

Comment: After some tries, I can see the Ubuntu logo. Thing is, it's the old loading screen I saw in 19.10 and previous. Still, I like that loading screen. Thanks