# Plymouth Docs for Creating Themes

Tags: themes, plymouth, documentation

I am trying to customize my bootsplash screen, using Plymouth themes. However, I cannot find any documentation for creating themes. Where can I find such documentation?

Comment: Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the plymouth bootscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen)

Comment: @vanadium helpful, and could probably get me closer to getting it working. However, the guide in the accepted answer is 11 years old. Idk how much is outdated by now, is there any newer, preferably something created and updated by the developers?