# Xubuntu Splash Showing When Prior Was Ubuntu Studio Theme

Tags: themes, boot-repair

*This is not a duplicate post as there is nothing relating to Ubuntu Studio that I can find that actually works with this issue.*

After a failed upgrade from Ubuntu Studio 21.04 to 21.10, I ended up having to use `boot-repair` to get it to boot once again. It is clearly still Ubuntu Studio but the bootup splash screen says Xubuntu and all the login and desktop screens are something else too with something like the outline of a squid on them. How can I restore the proper desktop? Is there some command to run that will do it? Apparently this release includes Plasma 5.22.5 and the theming uses the Materia theme and icons are Papirus icons.

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm` shows
gdm3
lightdm (as the current)
sddm

`sudo apt update` does not show any any *hirsute* and `sudo apt full-upgrade` runs without any errors.

Ubuntu Studio (for those who don't know) is no different than Ubuntu other than it comes pre-installed with a full suite of multimedia and graphics applications.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the plymouth bootscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen)

Comment: I would ensure your system is fully *impish* (ie. 21.10) and that the failed upgrade didn't leave you with a partially upgraded system (if you `sudo apt update` does any *hirsute* show?  I'd expect no; if you `sudo apt full-upgrade` are all package upgraded with no warnings/errors etc).  At the greeter you can select your session (it sounds like you already had Xfce installed; ie. maybe upgraded from a 20.04 Xfce based Studio to 20.10 KDE without re-install maybe..)   You can change the DM too to make it default (check what you have installed and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm` or equiv.)

Comment: Ubuntu Studio, Lubuntu & Kubuntu default to using `sddm` but a failed-upgrade & boot-repair should not have added Xfce packages so your description is missing details; let alone what you meant by "*failed upgrade*".  I'd worry more about ensuring your system is upgraded correctly as Xfce/Ubuntu-Studio plymouth, greeter/DM etc. are petty & easily changed...  Xfce should not be included without a reason (such as did you fail to re-install if using a Ubuntu-Studio 20.04 or earlier before using later KDE versions?)

Comment: Thank you all. I'll check these things and post results to my original question once I'm back on the system. By failed upgrade, I mean that it would not boot after the upgrade. The upgrade completed and there were no errors of any sort during or after so I am unable to be more specific other than it appeared that Grub had become corrupt. All that would come up was a blank screen with the moveable cursor on it.

Comment: There is nothing different/unique abut Ubuntu Studio (*other than additional packages added on the standard Ubuntu base*), in fact you can add Ubuntu Studio's *magic sauce* to any Ubuntu *flavor* (see https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/) so `plymouth` & DM are standard (Kubuntu, Lubuntu & Ubuntu Studio use the same); with the duplicate link applying to my Ubuntu system (a Lubuntu) & yours (Ubuntu Studio, *legacy* with Xfce or *modern* with KDE)

Comment: Your `dpkg-reconfigure` shows you using a non-standard default, plus other options that shouldn't exist on a *clean* Ubuntu Studio install - making me think you didn't use Ubuntu Studio media; OR upgraded to KDE from a Xfce install (*unsupported* by Ubuntu Studio) as only `sddm` belongs there. Choose it for a default Ubuntu Studio login screen (for Ubuntu Studio 20.10 & later) but your installation of GNOME (gdm3) & Xfce software was user changes prior to upgrade (ie. 21.04 or before and not the *release-upgrade*) in my opinion.

Comment: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/21.04/release/ubuntustudio-21.04-dvd-amd64.manifest shows what you'd expect; ie. only `sddm` has been using since Ubuntu Studio 20.10; it (Xfce or Gnome components) won't have been added by your use of boot-repair so that's most likely issues done on 21.04 or previous.  Refer my prior comments for making it return to default (ie. plymouth, sddm etc)

Comment: I did the upgrade to 21.10 through terminal and there were no warnings or errors. That said, after just now changing the default per these tips, the bootup splash looks much better. It does not say Ubuntu Studio as it used to but it does say Ubuntu and is a nice image which is fine. However, one of my dual displays now has a mostly black screen with only the menu in white across the top across the top and the task bar at the bottom and those are entirely different than they were prior. This is the primary display so it is currently a bit awkward. Still looking to see what is causing it.

Comment: I would start a new question about the display issue; I can't help with that sorry (details of what video card etc should be provided, what kernel module you're using for display/video drivers for example; `sudo lshw -C display` or equiv. may help) as this question is about a Xubuntu splash/plymouth screen.  I suspect the display issue relates to 5.11 kernel (21.04) being upgraded to 5.13 (21.10) but that doesn't relate to the issue this question is about.

Comment: After all that, I think I found the problem just now totally by chance. It appears that the update did so as Ubuntu rather than as Ubuntu Studio! I started noticing (in the back of my mind) that the menu had only standard Ubuntu apps linked rather than the multimedia suite of Ubuntu Studio but once I realized it consciously, I knew why. Is there any way it can be reverted or redone using Ubuntu Studio?

Comment: Updated from the command line as I typically do so not sure why it upgraded to Ubuntu rather than to Ubuntu Studio and I can find no way to revert it. Ubuntu Studio is not one of the choices at login either. I started a new thread for that here but no joy so far: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378120/21-10-upgrade-changed-versions?noredirect=1#comment2374496_1378120

Comment: All flavors of Ubuntu (inc. Ubuntu Studio) are built on the same Ubuntu base.  The base Ubuntu provides the *release-upgrade* functions which applies for all *flavors*; and that *release-upgrade* works purely based on the installed packages (so it'll keep you on the desktop it was before, eg. GNOME won't be added if you didn't have any GNOME; but if you had installed parts of GNOME, more of GNOME can be dragged in because of changes in *depends* rules between releases).  If parts of a desktop were missing that would need *resolving* which is done via adding more or removing more.

Comment: I would have expected that to be true, yet after the upgrade it was no longer the same desktop theme as before and the theme ubuntustudio is no longer one of the choices.