# I screwed up Ubuntu by installing KDE Plasma alongside GNOME

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, kde

I wanted to try out KDE on my Ubuntu. Then I found out I need another system (Kubuntu), but I found a way to install Plasma on regular Ubuntu (apt install kde-standard). I did so, and i succesfully logged in into KDE. At first, there was a problem: no matter which session I choose at the Session dropdown at the login screen, I can't get into GNOME. It worked for a bit, until it logged me out, and I couldn't log in back. I booted into recovery mode, dropped into root prompt, removed kde-standard and booted back. But the KDE login screen is there. And I can log in, but when I do, I get a yellow screen where I can slightly see GNOME. This lasts for a few seconds, then it crashes back to the log in screen. Is there a way to fix that without reinstalling?

**`neofetch --stdout` output (recovery root prompt):**

```sh
root@Marcel-UBU 
--------------- 
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64 
Host: MS-7D18 2.0 
Kernel: 5.19.0-43-generic 
Uptime: 1 min 
Packages: 2469 (dpkg) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Terminal: root 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-11400 (12) @ 4.400GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate 
Memory: 178MiB / 15896MiB
```

Comment: *I am at Windows right now, this is a dualboot setup.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** In order to better diagnose your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks

Comment: FYI:  You can have multiple desktops installed; I'm a *lover* of it, but complications can occur depending on what you do/install/remove etc.. You can also re-install Ubuntu Desktops (esp *flavors*) non-destructively. By KDE login you likely mean the DM (Kubuntu uses `sddm` by default; that isn't part of KDE as its where you login & KDE Plasma or the DE only starts after you've logged in) or maybe the `plymouth` screen... as these aren't part of the DEsktop you change them if you want something else. I don't understand your situation currently so can't offer any help

Comment: Well, probably that's `plymouth`, I've seen something about it on the boot console. @guiverc

Comment: The Plymouth screen is just a graphic that shows & hides the boot messages that are default on any POSIX/Unix (inc. Linux) type of OS as many users find them scary... it's installed when you add desktop packages, but won't change until you direct it to change (ie. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen etc).. On installing a new plymouth screen (likely if you installed KDE) you're asked which you want to use.. You need to just select another, but it's only a screen/wallpaper & doesn't influence anything (just shown on screen pre-DM/greeter)

Comment: When apt installing I selected sddm, 'cause this is the KDE one. How do i revert? @guiverc

Comment: The KDE Display Manager is actually `kdm`, but Kubuntu uses `sddm` as `kdm` is largely deprecated...  You can use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm` which will return to configuring it & select another (`sddm` could be any installed DM too, eg. `gdm3` is the default for recent Ubuntu Desktops with GNOME)  FYI: Lubuntu using LXQt & Ubuntu Studio also use `sddm` as their DM

Comment: Going to try it out, thanks. Btw, i can't get any further than a root prompt in recovery, so sudo is redundant. @guiverc

Comment: create a new user and login with this user. Usually the GUI problems are somewhere in the users profile.

Comment: @guiverc Almost fixed it. One problem left: there's the KDE cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this (not 100%):

1. First, boot selecting these options in `GRUB`: "Advanced options for Ubuntu" > "Ubuntu with [any kernel] (recovery mode)"
2. Select "network", enable, then "root", enter
3. Uninstall the package you used: `kde-full`, `kde-standard`, `kde-plasma` using `apt`.
4. Run `dpkg-reconfigure sddm`, select `qdm3` there.
5. Restart either with `resume` in the recovery menu or a reboot
6. The GNOME login screen should greet you. Log in.
7. If it's been uninstalled, install `ubuntu-desktop`, then log out and in.
8. Go to Settings > Appearance, select a color and a light/dark theme so the appearance returns to normal.

What's left:

- The cursor from the KDE theme you chose before fixing