# Install Kubuntu instead of Ubuntu 22.04, while keeping everything

Tags: gnome, system-installation, kubuntu, 22.04, kde

I've installed Ubuntu alongside Windows on my PC, but I realized I don't like GNOME. And I liked KDE Plasma much more. For that, I need Kubuntu. I had an attempt to install it on regular Ubuntu, but [that went horribly wrong](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1471372/i-screwed-up-ubuntu-by-installing-kde-plasma-alongside-gnome/1471870#1471870). So, is there a way to completely install Kubuntu **instead** of Ubuntu, while keeping configurations in `/etc` and `~`'s hidden files, the packages and snaps, `/home` and pretty much everything?

Comment: You can sign in to firefox to sync your browsing data and extensions

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. While you could install Kubuntu without reformatting the root directory, this would not remove Gnome Shell. Such install also should be done only with the same operating system version as the one that was installed.

The most clean approach will be to reinstall fresh and then restore a backup of your ~, including hidden files if you want to preserve all user configuration. After that, it is easy enough to reinstall software as you need it, and I doubt there is much custom configuration you did yourself in `/etc`. That is also easily reapplied if needed.

On the other hand, it is not bad practice to just clean install from time to time, then reinstall and reconfigure as the need arizes. This constitutes an efficient spring cleanup.

In general, though, installing the `kde-standard` session should work, as having multiple desktops installed is supported. After logging in to the KDE desktop, you may then (very carefully) remove components and tools that come with the Gnome desktop. Not sure what went wrong in your previous attempt.

Comment: What about packages and snaps with their configurations? For example, i want Firefox to be installed and configured (+logged in) after i reinstall.

Comment: "No, there isn't". You cannot install a different operating system preserving all data. You will be lucky where Firefox will be installed - it is a default app in Kubuntu. For configuration, you will need to restore that yourself.

Comment: Oh crap... That's much to do.

Comment: 15 minutes more. It is restoring your user data that may take most time.

Comment: It's reinstalling stuff that will take A LOT of time.